# c# - Atualizar planilha excel com texto de textbox

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, textbox

Estou tentando atualizar os dados de uma planilha pelo textbox. Tentei o código abaixo e o mesmo não gerou nenhuma exceção, mas não atualizou a planilha.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.CommandText = "update [Designa$] set Nome = '" + textBox1.Text + "' where Cod = '"+textBox2.Text+"'";
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Nome",textBox1.Text));
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Cod", textBox2.Text));

                MessageBox.Show("Dados Atualizados....");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Tira as aspas do Cod e vê se da certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

funcionou aqui! Segue o código:

string sFileXLSX = "caminho do seu.xlsx";
string strConnXLSX ="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + sFileXLSX + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

```
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnXLSX))
        {
            
            string strSQL = "UPDATE [Tabela$] SET Coluna = @ultima WHERE nome = '" + textBox1.Text +"'";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ultima", "22/03/2021");
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode utilizar o `OleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(string parameterName, Object value)` Tenta assim:

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        try
        {

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE [Designa$] SET Nome = @Nome WHERE Cod = @Cod";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome",textBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cod", textBox2.Text);

            MessageBox.Show("Dados Atualizados....");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Pessoal, tentei os 2, mas sem sucesso. Faz a mesma coisa, vai direto pra messagebox.

Comment: Manda o que ta escrito na textbox pra gente

Comment: Na textbox1, coloco o nome que quero que vá para a planilha. Ex: João Silva
Na textbox2, coloco o código que corresponde a linha do nome a ser atualizado. Ex: Cod. 1  Nome: João Pereira Silva

Answer (score 0):

Você está procurando o `Cod` como se fosse uma `string` e ele não é uma string e sim um número.
Remova as aspas e deve funcionar:

```
command.CommandText = "update [Designa$] set Nome = '" + textBox1.Text + "' where Cod = " + textBox2.Text;
```